# Drag and Drop PDF Attachments From Outlook To Chrome PHP SITE with DropFile.js

Tags: javascript, php, html, drag-and-drop

I use Micorsoft Outlook 2010. I constantly have to upload pdf attachments to my website that come from my outlook. My normal operation is to save to my hard drive and then upload to my site. I am hoping to cut out the step of saving to my hard drive and instead drag and drop the directly from my outlook email to my site. I use DropZone.js for my upload function. Can this be done?

Comment: What version of Windows are you on?

Comment: The issue will be getting Outlook to pass the file data w/o saving it locally. I'd look into what Outlook as as far as feasibility for that.